# Change sails.js EJS views to use .html extensions instead of .ejs extensions?

Tags: javascript, sails.js

Is it possible to configure sails.js apps to use `.html` extentions rather than `.ejs` (but still use the `ejs view engine`)?

`sails new app` creates `./views/home/index.ejs` and `./views/layout.ejs`.

I'd like to change the extensions to `.html` but keep everything else working the same way.

ie: I would now have `./views/home/index.html` and `./views/layout.html`, and the home page would still be injected into the layout page, as per normal.

How can I configure this please?

Comment: Does this change provide any speed improvements? Or what was your reason for wanting to change this?

Comment: No speed improvement, just preferred having my views with an `.html` extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `config/views.js`:

```
engine: {
  ext: 'html',
  fn: require('ejs').renderFile
},
```

Seems though that the future support for this feature is not guaranteed, since they removed this from docs, so use with caution.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach

Sails provides EJS templating by default.To override this and to use .html files , here is a simple solution. In your Sails App , go to config/routes.js. You will see following code there

```
module.exports.routes = {

 /***************************************************************************
 *                                                                          *
 * Make the view located at `views/homepage.ejs` (or `views/homepage.jade`, *
 * etc. depending on your default view engine) your home page.              *
 *                                                                          *
 * (Alternatively, remove this and add an `index.html` file in your         *
 * `assets` directory)                                                      *
 *                                                                          *
 ***************************************************************************/

 '/': {
   view: 'homepage'
 }

 /***************************************************************************
 *                                                                          *
 * Custom routes here...                                                    *
 *                                                                          *
 *  If a request to a URL doesn't match any of the custom routes above, it  *
 * is matched against Sails route blueprints. See `config/blueprints.js`    *
 * for configuration options and examples.                                  *
 *                                                                          *
 ***************************************************************************/

};
```

Remove the route to '/' as shown below . Keep it blank

New routes.js will look like

```
module.exports.routes = {

   //Remove '/' :)

};
```

Okay !!! now it’s done you can use your HTML files in Sails app . Put your index.html in assets folder . Sails will now load views from here :)

Answer (score 0):

In latest sails.js 0.11, this also valid:

```
engine: 'ejs',
extension: 'html',
```

To check how they do this, in /node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/views/configure.js:

```
if (typeof sails.config.views.engine === 'string') {
    var viewExt = sails.config.views.extension || sails.config.views.engine;
    sails.config.views.engine = {
        name: sails.config.views.engine,
        ext: viewExt
    };
}
```