# Using HTML instead of ejs in sails

Tags: angularjs, sails.js, sails.io.js, sails-postgresql

I am a newbie on **sails framework** and I started working on it then found that everything is in **ejs**. When I converted it into the HTML then it didn't work.

How to write client-side in HTML using AngularJS without ejs or with least ejs possible if we cannot remove it totally.

Where to write client-side routes and how to use `ui-router` in that?

Comment: you can use sails framework as an API server and client side as different server(grunt) just a suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change sails.js EJS views to use .html extensions instead of .ejs extensions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013180/change-sails-js-ejs-views-to-use-html-extensions-instead-of-ejs-extensions)

Comment: You will get `angular-sails` boilerplate which will help you a lot. [check this out](https://github.com/tarlepp/angular-sailsjs-boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

You should place your angular code in `assets/js`. The html files are also to be placed in `assets` folder.

I have set up a basic sails/ angular app in github. [Angular Demo](https://github.com/mjzac/AngularDemo)