# How to generate sailsjs without templating

Tags: sails.js

How to generate sailsjs project without any template engine (like ejs etc..). The closest thing that i found was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21013180/change-sails-js-ejs-views-to-use-html-extensions-instead-of-ejs-extensions). But it does not completely remove ejs. How do I proceed with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to completely disable views in your sails open `.sailsrc` and and file should look like this:

```json
{
    "hooks": {
        "views": false
    }
}
```

But i'm not sure that's the thing you want to do.

If you want to serve static html pages just put them into `/assets` and they will go through without any template engine.

Also take a look at [Consolidate.js](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js). Those are all template engines supported by Sails.js. Maybe you will find there something you like.

Comment: It's possible the OP is just trying to make an API, which wouldn't have the need for a front-end at all.  In that case, turning off the views hook would do the trick!